# Angular 2, select option issue

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material2

In Angular 2, I created a select(drop-down menu) with dynamic options(categories in this case) and one option which calls a function to create a new category which gets added to the select option list (i.e the drop-down menu).

```
  <md-select name="categories" (change)="categoryChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" floatPlaceholder="never" #categorySelect>
    <md-option (click)=openAddCategoryDialog(proj)>Add Category</md-option>
    <md-option *ngFor="let curr of proj['data'][0].Category" [value]="curr">{{curr.name}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

When I select "Add Category" from the select dropdown and create a new category, I want the Select to display the previous value which was displayed in the select field. It currently doesn't display anything in this case. If I switch between other values the selected category is displayed.

How do I make the select display the previously selected category on selection of 'Add Category' ?

Comment: I think it would be best to move the Add Category functionality out of the select. The problem you are having is being caused because when you click Add Category, you are changing the value of the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to disable the `Add Category` option

```
<md-option (click)=openAddCategoryDialog(proj) disabled>Add Category</md-option>
```

This will ensure that the dropdown doesn't change to `Add Category`, but at the same time still fire the click event to add a new category. Here is a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kebtji?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html) demoing this.

---

As per my comment, this functionality feels odd and like a workaround. I would recommend moving the Add Category functionality out of the select.

Comment: I understand this is an odd functionality but it is a requirement of sorts. Thank you for your answer. My functionality now works as intended. :)